# Статистика посещаемости на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, svg

Задумка ввести свою статистику посещаемости на сайте.

Первое что приходит в голову это записывать каждый уникальный ip в файл с новой строки. Каждые новые сутки это новый файл txt или svg.

Второе это сохранять записи в базе дынных.

На данный момент посещаемость не высока 500-100 уником и реализация как первая так и вторая работает быстро и нормально.

Вопрос:

Что будет если посещаемость вырастит в десятки или сотни раз?

К примеру как долго будет считываться количество строк с файла если в нем к примеру 50к записей? Так же интересует как долго будет идти подсчет в базе данных когда записей будет 1 миллион а нужно посчитать к примеру только все записи в таблице где дата только за сегодня, месяц, год.

Подскажите как все же лучше ввести статистику, или подскажите другие способы реализации.

Comment: БД имеет встроенные средства, позволяющие избегать проблем при одновременных операциях вставки записей в таблицу. Сомневаюсь, что такие средства есть у PHP - а попытка доступа к файлу, в который в данный момент пишет другая копия скрипта, вполне вероятна. И это только на стадии накопления. Когда же дойдёт до статистики - тут БД уделает текстовый лог по всем параметрам.

Comment: То есть вы считаете хранить все в БД правильным решением?

Comment: Да, конечно. Заодно отпадёт надобность потом переделывать.

Comment: А что вы скажите о скорости работы? Когда записей в таблице будет более 1 миллиона

Comment: Скажу, что преждевременная оптимизация - зло. А обработать миллион записей для СУБД - это тьфу, и растереть...

Comment: Благодарю за предоставленную информацию